# GraphQl generate Syntax Error: Expected $, found {]

Tags: react-native, graphql, apollo-client

```
    laugh  =async()=>  {
    let mutation = gql`
    mutation SignUp({$Email: String!
      $Password: String!
    }){
       SignUp(data: {
        Email: "tael32@gmil.com"
        Password: "12345678"
      }) {
        User {
          _id
          Name
          Rating
          Photo
          Badge
          Email
        }
        Token
      }}
    `;
    try {
      let data = await client.mutate({mutation});
      console.log('TCL: login -> data', data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Majid', error);
    }
  }
```

when i call this function it generate error in code while it run correctly in post

```
mutation {
  SignUp(data: {
    Email: "chetanvirani@gmail.com"
    Password: "12345678"
    Name: "Chetan"
  }) {
    User {
      _id
      Name
      Rating
      Photo
      Password
      Badge
      Email
    }
    Token
  }
}
```

here the code which run in postman but not in a code,i don't know what was was the error in my code

Answer (score 0):

Curly braces specify a selection set. There's no reason to wrap your variable definitions in curly braces:

```
mutation SignUp($Email: String!, $Password: String!) {
  ...
}
```